# `shell-command` repeats my input characters multiple times

Tags: shell, shell-command, comint

whenever I run this command `(shell-command "chatgpt install &")`  my input characters gets repeated like this:

> 1> hi hi
>
> Hello! How can I assist you today?
>
> 2> hi again  hhii  aaggaaiinn
>
> Hello! Welcome back. How can I help you today?
>
> 3> hi again again  hhhiii   aaagggaaaiiinnn   aaagggaaaiiinnn
>
> Hello once again! I'm here to assist you. What can I do for you this
> time?
>
> 4> hi again again again  hhhhiiii    aaaaggggaaaaiiiinnnn
> aaaaggggaaaaiiiinnnn    aaaaggggaaaaiiiinnnn

when I run the same command from vterm the input does not get repeated at all.

I tried:
run `async-shell-command` directly instead of `shell-command`

giving parameters to `shell-command` for `output-buffer` and `error-buffer`

setting `comint-process-echoes` to t

non of those worked.

**emacs version:** GNU Emacs 29.0.92 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2023-06-25